# Difference-in-differences model: do I have to include hierarchical terms with interaction term?

Tags: interaction, stata, difference-in-difference

I am contemplating using a DiD model to see the effect of an intervention on population attitudes. My DVs of interest are ordinal (Likert-style) and binary. I have two agencies measured at two time periods--one received the intervention, one did not. I'm using Stata.

My understanding is that, to construct a DiD, you create an interaction variable with timevariable*groupvariable (time1=0, time2=1, controlgroup=0, treatmentgroup=1), and include all terms in your model; i.e. ologit outcomescale interactionvariable timevariable groupvariable. While this does make theoretical sense to me, is there any occasion for leaving out the time and group variables and having just the interaction term? Also, are there any unseen issues in using DiD for ordinal logit or regular logistic regression?

Comment: One "unseen" (or maybe many times "ignored") issue is not meeting the Parallel Assumption which states that the treated individuals would have reacted in a similar fashion as the controls had they not been treated.  If your treated individuals are very different from the controls because of selection bias, then ignoring that assumption can lead to very bizarre (and wrong) conclusions.  And with just two time periods this assumption is not testable.

Comment: I think you mainly need to think about the parallel assumption and think how it might be justified (i.e., convincing others).  I would generally argue that this is a subjective/subject matter decision rather than a statistical decision.  Things can get a little complex if with a binary response the controls start with say a proportion of 0.8 which drop to 0.2 and the treated start with a proportion of 0.2.  The treated can't drop 0.6 "units" violating the parallel assumption.  But maybe on a logistic scale.  Sorry for the indefinite answer.  (It depends on the measurement scale.)

Comment: Let's say it's an intervention teaching youth about marijuana at an after-school program. Say we have two programs--one with education, one without. The youth are roughly similar in background, reasons for being there, etc. Measurements in attitudes are taken at times 1 & 2 in each group. However, the proportion of kids using MJ varies wildly between the 4 samples. Obviously, use affects attitudes. Is this something that could be controlled by simply including the MJ use variable in the DiD equation, or does it undermine the parallel assumption and we realize we can't approach it that way?

Comment: P.S. Jim Baldwin, the measurement scales are coded 1 to 10 from Likert scales, except for a few yes/no questions.

Comment: You may find [this paper](http://kooperationen.zew.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Redaktion/DFGFLEX/dp3478.pdf) illuminating.